# The easiest way to get default form values in a HTML form from a page source retrieved via Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy

I want to modify my profile information on a site and I'm using Indy for this. My question is: when I GET (via Indy) the contents of the profile page, that page will have a form with all the previous filled info checked/completed. If I want to change that info, I have to POST (via Indy) all the previous (unchanged) values and the changed ones, otherwise, if I POST only the values I want to change, the unchanged ones will be registered as empty and thus get nulled off my profile. My question is, is there an easy way to get the prefilled values from the HTML of the form so I can them re-post (and modify where needed) them?

Comment: Use an HTML parser?

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution. At the moment, with this question, I'm just looking for different opinions/suggestions (if any) so I know the fastest/easiest/free route

Comment: Well, start by forgetting Regex as a possibility.

Comment: You might have better luck automating a `TWebBrowser` or similar embedded browser (such as Chromium).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe string component for this, it's very simple, you need to use :

```
function  ALFastTagReplace(const SourceString, TagStart, TagEnd: AnsiString;
                           ReplaceExtendedProc: TALHandleTagExtendedfunct;
                           StripParamQuotes: Boolean;
                           ExtData: Pointer;
                           Const flags: TReplaceFlags=[rfreplaceall];
                           const TagReplaceProcResult: Boolean = False): AnsiString; overload;
```

example :

```
 ALFastTagReplace(MyHtmlString, // Const SourceString, 
                  '<input' // TagStart, 
                   '>', // TagEnd: AnsiString;
                   function(const TagString: AnsiString;
                                   TagParams: TALStrings;
                                   ExtData: pointer;
                                   Var Handled: Boolean;
                                   Const SourceString: AnsiString;
                                   Var TagPosition, TagLength: integer): AnsiString;
                   begin
                     Myprefilledvalues.add(TagString + '=' + TagParams.values['value'])
                   end,
                   true, // StripParamQuotes 
                   nil); // ExtData
```

Comment: Any idea as to why I get this when I try your code?
E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'ALFastTagReplace' that can be called with these arguments
E2009 Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'

Comment: Hmm i don't know like this, maybe you can ask in the support of https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe pasting your code that is faulty

Comment: Never mind that, I actually got it to work by separating the ReplaceExtendedProc from the function. But another question would be, what is the TagString constant and what should it display? I mean when I run the code I get =value; =anothervalue. What should TagString output before the = sign?

Comment: All in all, thanks! Using this I've solved my problems in a neat, fast way.